# How I can reorganize my hole old blogs in to a organization group for analytics

Tags: google-analytics, configuration, blogger

I was configúrate properly my blogs in 2008 but now I have to reorganize them with a label, but the instructions are so dispersed so I can’t do that on my own so I need your help by phone or maybe someone can do that for me. Thank you
Roser

Having all my blogs on google analytics and monetizing them if posible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.